# Objective-C message being sent to superclass

Tags: objective-c

I have derived a class SignalView from UIView however when I send a message to my object of type SignalView it gets sent to a UIView and I get error :

```
-[UIView Initialise]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b3900
```

my object also appears as a UIView object in the debug watch window:

```
m_signalview    UIView *    0x001b3900
```

the relevant code is:

```
// signalview.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SignalView : UIView
{   

}

-(void)Initialise;

@end


//signalview.m

#import "SignalView.h"

@interface SignalView ()

@end

@implementation SignalView

-(void)Initialise
{

}



// viewcontroller.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SignalView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet SignalView *m_signalview;

@end


// viewcontroller.m
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize m_signalview;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"%@", m_signalview);
    [m_signalview Initialise];
}
```

Comment: Your method names should be lowercase. It's a strong Obj-C  convention

Comment: Also property names don't start with `m_` or `_`, that's for ivars.  The @synthesize directive is optional for most properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that `m_signalview` is an `IBOutlet`.
Are you connecting that to a `UIView` you added in Interface Builder?
If so you might need to set the right class in its properties so that the loader can create an object of the right class.

Answer (score 4):

H2C03 is right.  its likely not a SignalView.  I would check your outlet in your view's nib file in the interface builder inspector make sure it doesn't still say UIView.  If it does change it to SignalView:

[image: before]

Should look like this:

[image: after]

Comment: filipe beat you by a minute :)

Answer (score 2):

Then it's simply an instance of `UIView` and not a `SignalView`. You're allocating and initializing `UIView` when you would need a `SignalView` instance. When you have something like this in your code:

```
m_signalView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

change it to

```
m_signalView = [[SignalView alloc] init];
```

Comment: as it's an IBOutlet, i suspect it is created in a nib

Comment: @hooleyhoop In that case, it's possible that Interface Builder doesn't recognize the custom class and creates a `UIView` instead. I wouldn't be surprised.